# what does "I'm just asking" mean in such a context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Everyone. Suppose there is a context like the following:
[Click to Watch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ev4n-dfjYAA)

**Woman**:Do you mind?
**Man**:Do I mind what?
**Woman**:**No**, I'm just asking...
**Man**:What?
**Woman**:I'm asking. Will you grate the cheese?

Which is the true meaning of the "I'm just asking" such concerned?

1. At this moment, It is I who am asking, or 2)I am only asking (without any intention of offending).
   Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you are asking what would be the meaning of a phrase in a conversation that you have made up? How can we possibly tell? When I read the first line of your dialogue, I don't know whether "Do you mind" here means "I want to make a polite request" or "I am objecting to what you are doing without being too rude about it",

Comment: @Colin Fine It's "Do you mind (grating the cheese)?". It is from a UK stage play "skylight".

Comment: Are you writing this? Because what the woman says is odd because we don't know what it refers to....

Comment: @Lambie, I am not the writer. It's from  "skylight", an award-winning stage play.

Comment: Kevin: if the dialogue is from a play, why didn't you tell us that at the beginning?

Comment: Also the name of the play's author (who apparently is David Hare).

Comment: But, even knowing what play it is (and I lit that play at Halifax Playhouse fifteen or twenty years ago), still does not give us enough context to interpret what any of the lines mean.

Comment: @Colin Fine Sorry. I should have given the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes when people say things, they don't mean the things they say.

Here it is played for laughs, and exaggerated. The woman uses lots of hints and clues from outside of spoken language.  The man fails to notice these and the comedy arises from their failure to communicate.

> **D'y'mind?** *(She shows the man a cheese grater, and it is apparent that she is preparing a meal, so this is short for "Do you mind grating the cheese", which is a tentative way to say "Please grate the cheese".)*
>
> **Do I mind what?** *(He ignores the clues, and interprets "D'y'mind" to mean "Are you offended?"  As there is nothing to be offended by, he asks for clarification.)*
>
> **No, I'm just asking...** *(Short for No, you have misunderstood me. I'm just asking you to grate the cheese.  Again she considers her gestures to provide enough context to understand that she talking about the cheese, even though she hasn't mentioned it yet. Here, "just" suggests that she considers the request to be a small one,  "I'm just asking for you to grate the cheese, and I'm not asking for you to do a longer or more difficult task, and nor am I asking a personal question about the thing that you "mind")*
>
> **What?**  *(He continues to consider only her words and ignores the other clues.  She hasn't specified her request in her words, so he asks her what she is asking.  It's not clear if he has a *social communication disorder* or is just pretending to misunderstand)*
>
> **I'm asking, "Will you grate the cheese".**  *(she explains her request, but even now she frames it as a quote, not a command or a request)*
>
> ...

There is so much more to communication than the words.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning is closer to "I am only asking (without any intention of offending)". The "just" usually modifies what follows; "I'm just six years old" doesn't mean "I'm the only one who is six ('just I')" but "I am only six."

But note, this whole dialogue is confusing to the point of being funny. Obviously, they're not communicating well; the man asks twice for clarification, and the woman thought her intent should have been clear without any words.

There are similar expressions like "I'm just saying..." which can be a bit ambiguous. For example: Watching your friend eat a bit of food that fell on the floor: "Are you sure you should eat that? I'm just saying..." Here the actual intent, "I think you shouldn't eat that," has been softened by a colloquial structure that merely questions it, and leaves a sentence dangling, with the remaining meaning to be implied.

Comment: "No, I'm just asking...", I think the "No" here should be noted.

Comment: @KevinCheng I don't know, it almost seems like a meaningless filler word (or word that stands in for a much wordier sentiment) in this context, like "How do you feel about this?" "No, yeah, it's great."

Comment: I trust the “No” there is "No question". Am I right?

Comment: @KevinCheng I don't think so. It's more meaningless. The whole dialogue, as I said, is very confused communication. We're lacking the context to tell what mood these lines are being spoken in, but I read it as:

Comment: @KevinCheng "Do you mind? [I shouldn't have to say anything at all; you should have grated the cheese without being reminded; and I'm making my anger clear despite cloaking it in sarcastic politeness.]" "Do I mind what? [Either being dense and truly unaware, or perhaps passive aggressive, forcing her to spell out what she's being reluctant to.]" "**No**, I'm just asking [—'No,' I didn't really literally mean 'do you mind,' I'm actually making a request."] OR maybe ["No, it shouldn't need spelling out," or even vaguer like "No, I don't mean to make a scene, I'm *just* asking"] or some such

Comment: But I could also read the scene as characterized by sincere and almost paralyzing shyness and hyper-politeness.

Comment: Search "The Cheese clip from Skylight" on Youtube you will get the scene. Contexts are truly more than words.

Comment: I've added the link to the video. Context will be the context itself now.

Comment: Yeah, suffice it to say that Kyra's first two lines, "Do you mind" and "No, I'm just asking" *mean nothing*. Her entire meaning is unstated and characterized by passive aggression, and she could very nearly have substituted any other two meaningless sentences with the same tone and context to provide the same unarticulated restrained animosity.

Comment: `just sayin'` is almost the canonical way of trying to avoid blame for something just said that is offensive, mean spirited, or just plain nasty.